# How to connect InputMethodService with a Service?

Tags: java, android, service, keyboard

I want to connect my custom Softkeyboard, which is expanding the InputMethodService, with another Service. I need to call a method in my Softkeyboard from a generic Service.

The problem is that i can not extend the Binder class because the method onBind() is defined final in the AbstractInputMethodService...

now, how can I call a method in my SoftKeyboard class from other service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this by using a broadcast receiver class.

```
    class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("GET_KEY_KEY")) {
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
                InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
                if (ic != null) {
                    ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT));
                }
        }

    }
}
```

then I sent a broadcast to my service.

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("GET_KEY_KEY");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
```